# Error on First Boot

Tags: linux, bios, fedora

I just built a new pc and on my first attempt to boot into the Fedora 28 XFCE spin I am getting the following error

```
 [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

Sometimes it stops at this message and other times it scrolls past some messages way to fast for me to read and then boots to the image on the USB.

Some people on other forums have suggested updating my bios or updating my processor's microcode. I am hoping someone may be able to confirm or deny this as well as give an explanation as to why this must be done

Comment: You are going to have to provide us more information about your system, specifically, which processor you have exactly.  In order to point you in the correct direction, so you can update your processor's microcode, per the error message we must have this information.  You should also supply information on your motherboard.  Please update your question with the requested information.

Comment: Any event, while within Fedora, you should run the command `sudo apt install intel-microcode`.  The simplest method of course would be just update the motherboard's firmware, by doing this, you will apply any applicable microcode updates permanently .